# Repository Browser Only - "Repository moved permanently to… please relocate”

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I have the repository root at http://localhost/svn/ and a couple of projects

```
http://localhost/svn/project1
http://localhost/svn/project2
http://localhost/svn/project3
...
```

TortoiseSVN works all the time with these projects, only every time I try to access the root http://localhost/svn/ by using "Repository Browser" it returns "Repository moved permanently to http://localhost/; please relocate", while I'm sure the root is fine as I can open it in browsers and see a list of all projects, it's just not working in "Repository Browser". Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suppose you have one SVN repository in each one of `svn/project1`, `svn/project2`, `svn/project3` -- and that you have no SVN-related anything in `svn`.

You can see the content of `svn` in a browser because that directory is served by your webserver -- but it's not served as an SVN-related thing : it's just an HTML page that's sent to your browser.

As such, TortoiseSVN cannot work with it : `svn` is not an SVN repository.

Comment: Cannot remember how it was created years ago, but your analysis really make sense and i think that should be it. So did i do wrong? Should i make the root a top level project?

Comment: I don't think you did *wrong* : One SVN repository per project makes perfect sense ; just don't try to use TortoiseSVN to explore directories which are not SVN repositories.

Comment: thanks, you made it clear, i always thought that is i did something wrong so that tortoisesvn threw the message

Answer (score 0):

This has more to do with your Apache server configuration. You must configure the root of your repository there. In other words, you must have some something like this in your configuration files of your localhost:

```
<Location /svn>
  DAV svn
  SVNPath /var/svn/repository
</Location>
```

This single repository is where your three projects must reside. If your projects reside in single repositories, then you will need three different locations in your Apache server configuration as well.

So, the question here is, do you have three different subversion repositories, or just three different project folders under the same repo?

You can read more about your Apache server configuration in the book [Version Control With Subversion](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/), specifically [Chapter 6](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/svn.serverconfig.html) on the section [The Apache Server](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/svn.serverconfig.httpd.html)

If you have multiple repositories as you seem to indicate, then you need to configure a `SVNParentPath`

```
<Location /svn>
  DAV svn

  SVNParentPath /var/svn
</Location>
```

And this should be where all your repos will reside on the server.

Comment: Should be the former, as when i new a project, what i do is right click in visualsvn server GUI and choose "Create new repository"

Comment: The you might consider revising if your path to the repository in the server is configured using SVNParentPath as I have suggested in the updated post.

Comment: Thanks, i can access the root thru http. Pascal is right, repository browser is for sure running on svn protocol so it is just not possible for it to recognize an os folder or http root